# R: creating continuous timelines

Tags: r

I have some data showing the duration individuals spent in states `a`, `b`, and `c`. The durations should not overlap. In my data, `c` sometimes overlaps with `a` and `b`. I am trying to correct the data so there are no overlaps. `a` and `b` take priority, so I am only changing the start or end dates of `c`.

For example, my data looks like this (for two individuals):

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), period = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", 
"c", "a", "b"), start = c(3L, 11L, 8L, 18L, 20L, 26L, 31L, 1L, 
11L, 13L, 15L, 16L), end = c(10L, 12L, 20L, 19L, 25L, 32L, 35L, 
10L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

And the desired output would be:

[image]

In this example, the individual with id == 2 has no time in period `c`, because periods `a` and `b` completely overlap.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

My method is a bit crude, but it'll work

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(start, end), names_to = "event", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = c("start", "end"), ordered = T)) %>%
  arrange(rowid, id, period, event) %>%
  mutate(val = ifelse(period == "c" & event == "start" & val < lag(val), lag(val)+1, val),
         val = ifelse(period == "c" & event == "end" & val > lead(val), lead(val)-1, val)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(rowid, id, period), names_from = event, values_from = val) %>%
  arrange(rowid) %>% mutate(start = ifelse(start > end, NA, start),
                            end = ifelse(end < start, NA, end)) %>%
  select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
      id period start   end
   <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 a          3    10
 2     1 b         11    12
 3     1 c         13    17
 4     1 a         18    19
 5     1 b         20    25
 6     1 c         26    30
 7     1 a         31    35
 8     2 a          1    10
 9     2 b         11    14
10     2 c         NA    NA
11     2 a         15    15
12     2 b         16    20
```

Adding `-` instead of `NA` will turn the column type from `dbl` to `chr`.

**EDIT** on second thoughts I propose smaller code

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(start = ifelse(period == "c" & start < lag(end), lag(end)+1, start),
         end = ifelse(period == "c" & end > lead(start), lead(start)-1, end),
         start = ifelse(start > end, NA, start),
         end = ifelse(start > end, NA, end))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
      id period start   end
   <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 a          3    10
 2     1 b         11    12
 3     1 c         13    17
 4     1 a         18    19
 5     1 b         20    25
 6     1 c         26    30
 7     1 a         31    35
 8     2 a          1    10
 9     2 b         11    14
10     2 c         NA    NA
11     2 a         15    15
12     2 b         16    20
```